# Add a group to all service connections in ADO

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Can anyone suggest how can we add a single group to all service connections in all projects under a single organization in Azure Devops. Any possibility to do it via cmd or any reference script? As the manual work in portal will take long time to finish.

Comment: Hi @prabhu, How are things going? Have you tried the latest suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please try it, and any progress, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Hi @prabhu, thanks for your reply. Could you please mark my answer as the solution of this topic? This may be very helpful to more people who are looking for a solution for the similar questions.

Comment: Its done Bright Ran. Thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the organization-level administrators can access all the service connections in all projects under an organization in Azure DevOps.

You can try to set the group as a member of **Project Collection Administrators** on the organization.

To view more details, you can see "[**Secure a service connection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#secure-a-service-connection)".

**[UPDATE]**

Once a Service connection is created, by default only the following two members are added on the **User permissions** section of this Service connection:

- the **Endpoint Administrators** group
- the creator of this Service connection

Generally, both of the two members will be set as **`Administrator`** role.

For other users, teams and groups, you need to manually add them to each Service connection and set their roles.

No any easy, quick way is available to set a group as the **`Reader`** role for all the Service connections in all projects under an organization.

**[UPDATE 2]**

You can try using the API "[**Update Service Endpoint**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/update%20service%20endpoint?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)" or "[**Update Service Endpoints**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/update%20service%20endpoints?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)" to set the readers group of the service connections.

There is a parameter "**`readersGroup`**" you can set up in the [Request Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/update%20service%20endpoint?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#request-body).

You can try use the API "[**Get Service Endpoints**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/get%20service%20endpoints?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)" to list all the service connections in each project. Then use "**Update Service Endpoint**" to set the readers group for each service connection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. here the requirement is to provide "Reader" access to group to all the service connections in all projects.

Comment: Hi @prabhu, I have updated my answer with more explanations. Please check it. If you have any questions about this, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Thanks for the update. In that case i need to manually go to each service connections to add a group as the Reader role. I thought some options would be there in Azure Devops API or powershell based..

Comment: Hi @prabhu, You can try using the API "**Update Service Endpoint**" to do that. More details, see the latest update in my answer.